# Is there a way to remove the line after the title of a document using the comsoc IEEETran class option?

Tags: ieeetran

[image: Example page. Looking to remove the line with the diamond in the middle that appears after the title]

Is there a way to remove the line with the diamond in the middle that appears after the title?

In case the title wasn't clear, I'm using `\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please have a look at Section 3 here: [The DuckBoat -- News from TeX.SE: Asking effective questions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf).

Comment: Whatever is mentioned above is the result incurred from Journal Template. You need to use the class embedded with conference option. Just something like this `\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line with the diamond is defined internally as `\IEEEcompsocdiamondline`. You can redefine this command to be empy and then the line disappears.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\def\IEEEcompsocdiamondline{}
\title{Filler}
\author{Filler}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

However, there is still a lot of vertical space between the title and the first section, due to the definition of `\@maketitle` in `IEEEtran.cls`. You can change the code there, or use a quick workaround and redefine the diamond line to some amount of negative vertical space:

```
\def\IEEEcompsocdiamondline{\vspace{-1.5cm}}
```

[image]

Note that if you use the class for a publication somewhere, the publisher may not allow any modifications to the appearance - but for personal or non-official use this is not an issue of course.